# IE7 text renders with way too much space?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, compatibility, space

IE 7's rendering:
[image: IE 7's rendering]
*Everything* else's rendering:
[image: Everything else's rendering]
There are a few problems between those two images, but the one I'm concerned with is that there is way too much spacing between lines. I set the line-spacing to 0px, and then the "page name here" at the top looks right, but everything else is messed up. Set everything else to 1.2 and everything looks somewhat fine... but that messes every other browser up. What should I do? Is there another property I'm missing, or do I have to ind a work-around?

Code:

The div around the top "Page Name Here"

```
#TopBar {
    padding: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 250;
}
```

The actual h1 element of the "Page Name Here"

```
.TitleText {
    font-size: 2em;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.2;
}
```

Everything:

```
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    line-height: 1.2;
}
```

I tried messing with the values a bit but I can only get it to look good on either IE7 or everything else

Comment: where is your relevant code?

Comment: did you create a reset css?  like this `* {margin:0; padding:0;}`

Comment: My suggestion: don't mind it. You can't expect all browsers to render exactly the same, there will always be some differences, specially with non-compliant browsers like IE7. Only try to fix them if they break the functionality, but a little of space isn't a big deal.

Comment: @HugoS.Mendes Yeah I did that with margin, and padding, and line-spacing

Comment: @Orial I don't mind the spacing in the body much, but the top text becomes cut off

Comment: I found the best approach is to avoid IE7. ;-)

Comment: @JonathanWood hahaha I wish that was an option but this is for a contest so they may hold that against me :/

Comment: There must be some other CSS cascading down that is interfering. What other CSS that you haven't shared is applied to `<h1.titleText>`?

Comment: @SetSailMedia yeah it turns out my * selector was the culprit all along, setting its top margin to auto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out while posting my code...

In my code:

```
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    line-height: 1.2;
}
```

I set the margin for everything to be auto by default, making IE7 render a different value other than 0px. By setting it to 0px for the margin-top property, it gets rid of the extra space at the top of the title bar and fixes the cutting off problem.

Comment: Good work, elaborate and accept this answer for others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

use this IE7 hack:

```
#TopBar { *height: 40px; }
```